# Return a pattern multiple times

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a column called `comment` that can contain a certain pattern as many as 5 times and I would like to return all of them. Here is the value I have in my colum:

> oijdwe wbjcwe  sbr ('JOJ.TTT.ABC', test) sdfjksj dlkfjs lkf qweiuh
>   ('JOJ.TTT.123', test) oiiqwd m lskc qu i ('JOJ.TTT.452', test) ksd
>   sdfskq azx  ('JOJ.TTT.ACD5', test)

I would like to return the following values: `JOJ.TTT.ABC`, `JOJ.TTT.123`, `JOJ.TTT.452` and `JOJ.TTT.ACD5`

when using the following statement

```
 select 
     regexp_substr(comment,'JOJ.T{3}.{4}',1,1)
     ,regexp_substr(comment,'JOJ.T{3}.{4}',1,2)
     ,regexp_substr(comment,'JOJ.T{3}.{4}',1,3)
     ,regexp_substr(comment,'JOJ.T{3}.{4}',1,4)
     ,regexp_substr(comment,'JOJ.T{3}.{4}',1,5)
 from blabla
```

it works fine if the pattern is `JOJ.TTT.XXX` but not in case there are 4 caracters after "TTT.". I know this is because of the {4} I am using. How can I get the result I want?

Thanks

Comment: I am not familiar with sql, so I can only comment on the regex part.  You can try to change `JOJ.T{3}.{4}` to 'JOJ\.T{3}\.[A-Z0-9]*'.

Answer (score 2):

Use `[^']+` to match *until* the next `'`.

```
 select 
      regexp_substr(comment_,q'!JOJ.T{3}[^']+!',1,1)   a,
      regexp_substr(comment_,q'!JOJ.T{3}[^']+!',1,2)   b,
      regexp_substr(comment_,q'!JOJ.T{3}[^']+!',1,3)   c,
      regexp_substr(comment_,q'!JOJ.T{3}[^']+!',1,4)   d,
      regexp_substr(comment_,q'!JOJ.T{3}[^']+!',1,5)   e
 from blabla;
```

I have changed `comment` into `comment_` since `comment` is a reserved keyword in Oracle.

Answer (score 1):

While the `.` in the regular expression works for this purpose, it will also match things you don't want, since it is a wildcard character. Use `\.` to match a literal `.`. You can also use `LEVEL` and `CONNECT BY` so you needn't write out multiple calls to `REGEXP_SUBSTR()` explicitly:

```
WITH x AS (
  SELECT 'oijdwe wbjcwe sbr (''JOJ.TTT.ABC'', test) sdfjksj dlkfjs lkf qweiuh (''JOJ.TTT.123'', test) oiiqwd m lskc qu i (''JOJ.TTT.452'', test) ksd sdfskq azx (''JOJ.TTT.ACD5'', test)' AS comment1
    FROM dual
)
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(comment1,'JOJ\.TTT\.[A-Z0-9]+', 1, LEVEL)
  FROM x
CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR(comment1,'JOJ\.TTT\.[A-Z0-9]+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL;
```

[See SQL Fiddle here.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/40670)

It gets a little kludgier if you have multiple columns and want to return them all:

```
WITH x AS (
  SELECT 1 AS id, 'oijdwe wbjcwe sbr (''JOJ.TTT.ABC'', test) sdfjksj dlkfjs lkf qweiuh (''JOJ.TTT.123'', test) oiiqwd m lskc qu i (''JOJ.TTT.452'', test) ksd sdfskq azx (''JOJ.TTT.ACD5'', test)' AS comment1
    FROM dual
   UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 AS id, 'oijdwe wbjcwe sbr (''JOJ.TTT.ABC'', test) sdfjksj dlkfjs lkf qweiuh (''JOJ.TTT.123'', test) oiiqwd m lskc qu i (''JOJ.TTT.452'', test) ksd sdfskq azx (''JOJ.TTT.ACD5'', test)' AS comment1
    FROM dual
)
SELECT id, REGEXP_SUBSTR(comment1,'JOJ\.TTT\.[A-Z0-9]+', 1, LEVEL)
  FROM x
CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR(comment1,'JOJ\.TTT\.[A-Z0-9]+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL
    AND PRIOR id = id
    AND PRIOR DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE IS NOT NULL;
```

[See SQL Fiddle here.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/40674) Without the `PRIOR` clauses Oracle will return a cross join of the values of `id` and of `comment1`.

By the way, `COMMENT` is an Oracle reserved word and the above queries did not work in 11g r2 with a column named `comment`. That is why I used `comment1` instead.

Alternately, you could use `[^'']+` instead of `[A-Z0-9]+` but given your example data I'm not sure that's what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I found how to fix it

> ```
> select 
>     regexp_substr(comment,'JOJ.T[^'']+',1,1)
>     ,regexp_substr(comment,'JOJ.T[^'']+',1,2)
>     ,regexp_substr(comment,'JOJ.T[^'']+',1,3)
>     ,regexp_substr(comment,'JOJ.T[^'']+',1,4)
>     ,regexp_substr(comment,'JOJ.T[^'']+',1,5) 
> from blabla
> ```